# how to get the page source and search with Watin

Tags: c#, search, watin

i'm using Watin and i want to search in the page source (HTML), like the ctrl+F search, what is the best way to do it?

thanx for any help,
Shiran

Comment: Did my answer assist you ?Things move fast at stackoverflow best you check every hour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you, that is a example of how to impliment it

```
        // Find text like ctr+F (NOT IN SOURCE BUT IN "WHAT YOU SEE"
        if (ie.Text.Contains("SOME TEXT TO FIND").Equals(true))
        {
            //Do stuff you would like when found here
            MessageBox.Show("Text Found! ");

        }
        else
        { 
            // cant find
        }

        //OR

        // Find text in SOURCE
        if (ie.Html.Contains("SOME TEXT TO FIND").Equals(true))
        {
            //Do stuff you would like when found here
            MessageBox.Show("Text Found! ");

        }
        else
        { 
            // cant find
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IE.Text](http://watin.sourceforge.net/doc/P_WatiN_Core_Document_Text.html) property to get the text of the whole page equivalent to innerText of the body element. Otherwise if you want the raw HTML you can use [IE.Html](http://watin.sourceforge.net/doc/P_WatiN_Core_Document_Html.html).